# JavaFX TableView performance issue while adding or deleting new rows

Tags: performance, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, javafx-2

I am trying to add some new rows to JavaFX TabelView once the ScrollPane which contains the TableView Pane attach to the bottom.

But the entire TableView will refresh even though I just add a single row.
This make the performance very bad when I have a huge number of data.

Is there any way to add a single row without re-load other rows which have loaded before?

The following is an demo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PaneDemo extends Application {

    private TableView<NodeInfo> table = new TableView<NodeInfo>();
    private final ObservableList<NodeInfo> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private static int index = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        TableColumn<NodeInfo, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NodeInfo, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NodeInfo, String>("lastName"));

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            data.add(new NodeInfo("first Name" + index, "last Name" + index++));
        }

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

        Button btn = new Button("add new item");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("-------------add a new row------------");
                data.add(new NodeInfo("first Name" + index, "last Name" + index++));
            }
        });

        final VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(table, btn);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class NodeInfo {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private NodeInfo(String fName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            System.out.println(lastName.get());
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String lName) {
            lastName.set(lName);
        }
    }

}
```

Through the demo, the console will print more and more rows with adding new rows.

Hope I made my self clear enough.

Comment: I've never encountered an issue with such a simple item class. Furthermore the performance should not depend on the number of `item`s but on the number of visible rows... BTW: you probably should add the appropriate property getters, i.e. `lastNameProperty()` and `firstNameProperty()`

Comment: the cells are reused - so it might  access the item properties on adding (aka: in a layout pass), but that's a constant number (visible rows plus some), independent on items size (as @fabian already noted)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just use this as a demo. And in my project the item class is much bigger than this one. Could you please tell why the performance depand on the number of visible rows? Is there any docs? @fabian

Comment: In my case, every time I add a new row the entire table will rebuild not only the visible rows ( much more than visible ones ). BTW, I also use cell factory to add CSS. @kleopatra

Comment: then you are doing something wrong in your real world application - provide an example that demonstrates the mis-behaviour

Comment: you can _see_ that the access depends on the # of visible rows: increase the data size to 50 k and add a row: the output prints about 2-3 times the visrows for the visible items, none for items that are not visible (except maybe one, two below and above the current viewport) - so don't understand where you see a problem.

Comment: @fabian thank you so much. You help me a lot. I have solved the issue. My problem is that I make the tableView visiable rows aline with all items.

Comment: @kleopatra thank you so much. You help me a lot. I have solved the issue. My problem is that I make the tableView visiable rows aline with all items.

Comment: tableView.setFixedCellSize(25);
  tableView.prefHeightProperty()
    .bind(tableView.fixedCellSizeProperty().multiply(Bindings.size(tableView.getItems()).add(1.1)));
  tableView.minHeightProperty().bind(tableView.prefHeightProperty());
  tableView.maxHeightProperty().bind(tableView.prefHeightProperty());